# iptables service not started because of error (SVC_RUN_EXCEPT)

Tags: 12.04, server, openvpn

I installed OpenVPN on my Ubuntu Server 12.04. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-openvpn-access-server-on-ubuntu-12-04). I managed to install it and can access the admin panel through my browser. However, when I try to start the server, this error `iptables service not started because of error (SVC_RUN_EXCEPT)` appears. I googled for it and seen numerous post pertaining `vz`, and AFAIK my VPN hosting which is DigitalOcean is using KVM. So those doesn't apply to me.

I even followed this [documentation](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides/186-how-to-run-access-server-on-a-vps-container.html) on OpenVPN site, however, it seems that I don't have this path `/etc/vz/vz.conf` which needs to be edited.

I'm totally lost in here and confused.

Answer (score 0):

Stuck with the same trouble.
Seems that openvpnas doesn't start after installing. Try the following:

```
sudo service openvpnas start
```